# Ação de click com jquery não funciona com itens duplicados

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, html5

Tenho dois botões na minha página que servem para deletar usuários, um eu coloquei na parte superior da tabela onde exibe os usuários junto com a paginação e o outro na parte inferior, também junto com a paginação. Coloquei assim para facilitar a navegação do usuário, mas as minha função jquery que é disparada pelo evento click desse botão, só funciona com o botão da parte superior, se eu colocar os botões com ids diferentes e duas funções separadas para cada um eles funcionam, mas queria um método que servisse para os dois.

```
//A função está mais ou menos assim
$("#deletar").click(function(){
    //Faz algo aqui
}
```

Testei alguns seletores do jquery, mas não obtive sucesso.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Os IDs têm de ser únicos. Ou seja só podes ter 1 por página.
Nestes casos deves usar classes para agrupar elementos com o mesmo identificador.

Muda:

- `#deletar` para `.deletar` no seletor do jQuery
- `id="deletar"` para `class="deletar"` no HTML.

Answer (score 1):

Não pode atribuir o mesmo `id` a [mais de um elemento na página](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/id). Se fizer isso, o DOM vai pegar sempre o primeiro `id` da página e ignorar o(s) outro(s).

Sendo assim, atribua um `id` para cada elemento que você quer clicar e adicione uma `class` igual para eles:

```
<input class="botoes" type="button" value="Botão 1" id="botao1" />
<br /><br />
<input class="botoes" type="button" value="Botão 2" id="botao2" />
```

Desta forma, quando o elemento for clicado, você pode pegar as informações das quais precisa com jQuery a partir da classe:

```
$('.botoes').on('click', function(){
    alert('Botão com "id='+this.id+'" clicado!');
});
```

```js
$('.botoes').on('click', function(){
 alert('Botão com "id='+this.id+'" clicado!');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input class="botoes" type="button" value="Botão 1" id="botao1" />
<br /><br />
<input class="botoes" type="button" value="Botão 2" id="botao2" />
```